# How to keep the order of elements in hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable, linkedhashmap

I have a hashtable . values() method returns values in some order different from the order in which i am inserted.How can i get the values in the same order as i inserted?Using LinkedHashmap is an alternative but it is not synchronized.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: LinkedHashMap is a part of Java.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> Hash table and linked list
>   implementation of the `Map` interface,
>   with predictable iteration order. This
>   implementation differs from `HashMap` in
>   that it maintains a doubly-linked list
>   running through all of its entries.
>   This linked list defines the iteration
>   ordering, which is normally the order
>   in which keys were inserted into the
>   map (*insertion-order*). Note that
>   insertion order is not affected if a
>   key is *re-inserted* into the map. (A
>   key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   `m.put(k, v)` is invoked when
>   `m.containsKey(k)` would return `true`
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)

combined with [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)).

So, for example:

```
Map<String, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(
  new LinkedHashMap<String, String>());
```

Comment: To clarify : If I'm not looking at having more then 1 tread access this `LinkedHashMap` at a time, would it still be recommended to synchronize it?  Or the `LinkedHashMap` on it's own would be considered enough?

Comment: @blo0p3r The `LinedHashMap` should be enough on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You could either wrap a `LinkedHashMap` and synchronize or you could use the `Collections.synchronizedMap` utility to create a synchronized [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
```

From the JavaDoc:

> If multiple threads access a linked hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap  method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the map

Comment: The performance overhead will be negligable (literally nanoseconds).

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the reason hashtables are unsorted is to aid storage and retrieval speed. Because of this I would suggest using an external structure to maintain ordering and just using the hashtable for storing values (for fast lookup).

Answer (score 2):

A hash table is inherently unordered, so you are using the wrong data structure.  Since you don't specify what language you are using I cannot suggest an alternate, but you need some type of ordered key/value set.

Answer (score 1):

If jdk1.6 you have only two type of ordered map EnumMap and LinkedHashMap. Both of them are not synchronized. If you just need to remember the order, use

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
```

if you want sorted then use ConcurrentSkipListMap