# Does Hashtable do sorting?

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have a dataset that I'm feeding into a hashtable:

```
Public Questions As Hashtable = New Hashtable        
Dim ds As DataSet = instCaisse.GetCaisseQuestions()

For i As Integer = 0 To (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
    Questions.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("questionPart"),ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("question"))
Next
```

When I feed the information from the database into my dataset (via stored procedure) everything is ordered alphabetically thanks to an order by in the stored proc's select statement.

When I load up the data from the hashtable, it appears unordered. Am I missing something, does hashtable do some sort of sorting that I'm not aware of?

In that respect I may end up just using a SortedList or a Dictionary to retain the ordering of the values. If that's the case which is the better option to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting Hashtable by Order in Which It Was Created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080667/sorting-hashtable-by-order-in-which-it-was-created)

Comment: You should use a SortedDictionary instead of a HashTable in this instance

Comment: SortedDictionary would be the way to go. Also, next time, I would suggest you use Dictionary instead of Hashtable.

Comment: The question is why are you using a `Hashtable` in the first place? Do you need the fast lookup?

Comment: I will just use a Dictionary for this then, but what's the difference between Dictionary and SortedDictionary, doesn't Dictionary already sort things?